# Unable to fetch from form data using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I am trying to take input from a form inside a modal and update that input field in postgres.
But when I am trying to fetch the input field the result is coming as undefined.

```
router.post('/changePassword', (req, res) => {
  const emailReq = req.session.email;
  const oldpasswordReq = req.body.password;
  const newpasswordReq = req.body.newpassword;
  if (oldpasswordReq !== newpasswordReq) {
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.newpassword, salt);
    knex('users').where({ email: emailReq })
      .update({ password: hash })
      .then(() => {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    res.render('/', { title: 'Password changed'});
  } else { (alert('The passwords are same')); };
});
```

The form within the modal is as below in a ejs file

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Change Password</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"><br><br>
<form method="post" action="/users/changePassword">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="usr">Old Password:</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="oldpassword" name="oldpassword">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pwd">New Password:</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="newpassword" name="newpassword">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="upload">Confirm</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it's related to you sending the data to `/users/changePassword`, but the router being configured to `/changePassword`?

Comment: I don't understand what "result is coming as undefined"?